# Message after sudden shutdown

Tags: shutdown

After the computer shuts down suddenly unexpectedly without notification, is there a way to know the reason (read messages) the next time when I boot? My computer frequently shuts down, and I don't even know if it is a software problem, a hardware problem, or a firmware problem.

Comment: Does it shutdown in a more or less controlled way or does it just power off? In the first case your filesystems do not need checking at boot, in the second your filesystems are automatically being checked.

Comment: @jippie The latter: it just powers off.

Comment: These issues are tough to solve. Make sure your hardware is in good condition; all fans running, no dust blocking the vents etc. I see you built the computer yourself, in that case you have sufficient knowledge to also check if all connectors are firmly in place.

Comment: @jippie So, do you think it is likely a hardware problem?

Comment: Don't know, it might. I slightly updated my comment above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would generally depend on your operating system, the type of computer you're using, and how abrupt the reboot was.

Many Unix-like operating systems (including the popular Linux-based ones) keep their logs in `/var/log`. On some others, `/var/adm` is the standard location. The specific files stored there depend on the OS, distribution and configuration. Look for `kernel` or `kernel.log`, then try `messages{,.log}` or `syslog{,.log}`.

Some non-Linux Unices can produce a full report of a crash whenever this happens. Check the OS docs on where the crash dump is stored, and how to read it.

If your computer has server management board, IPMI board, or somesuch, the reason for the reboot may be recorded there. Check the logs via the web interface or `ipmitool`. If your mainboard has a dumber watchdog, the watchdog may be responsible for the reboot but this won't be logged.

If you still can't find any information, there are two cases: either the reboot is too sudden for the logs to be written (consider mounting your `/var` partition `sync` **temporarily** — it's a serious performance hog), or there *are* no logs to be written. In the latter case, the issue is either a very low-level hardware fault or a power supply issue (e.g. the POWEROK signal from the power supply de-asserting and causing a hardware reset, or a half-dead laptop battery behaving strangely — the laptop I'm on right now has been known to do this occasionally when running on battery power).

Comment: The computer was built my myself. The motherboard is Intel brand. The power is taken from AC, but I use a power unit called pico psu. I modified it a little bit with soldering, so I may have damaged it, or maybe the power capacity is not enough (the unit only allows about 60W). The OS is linux mint 13. Following your suggestion, I looked for the files, and there are files named `/var/log/kern.log.*`, `/var/log/syslog.*`. I will try to look into these. Thanks.

Comment: PS. The reboot does not happen automatically. It just shuts down. I have to manually do it, sometimes failing.

Comment: @saw Have a look at http://www.mcelog.org/ if it is a hardware problem and you have the right hw this may help

Comment: @UlrichDangel Thanks. I just installed it.